# Angular dynamically swap SASS styles depending on environment

Tags: angular, webpack, sass

I am using Angular 6 with the new angular.json file where I have configured a separate configuration. In this new configuration I am swapping out my constants.scss for constants.newconfig.scss.

It compiles correctly when running ng serve --configuration=newconfig but for some reason it is still using the original constants.scss.

Here is the default config for production in the angular.json

```
"configurations": {
  "production": {
  ...
  "fileReplacements": [
    {
      "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
      "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
    }
  ]
  ...
```

and here is what I have added.

```
"configurations": {
  "production": { ...Prod stuff... },
  "newconfig": {
  ...
  "fileReplacements": [
    {
      "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
      "with": "src/environments/environment.newconfig.ts"
    },
    {
      "replace": "src/constants.scss",
      "with": "src/constants.newconfig.scss"
    }
  ]
  ...
```

Would this have something to do with how webpack precompiles sass so by the time Angular replaces the constants file, webpack has already modified the filesystem.

---

#### Update

- My constants.scss are imported at the top of my root styles.scss
- It seems to use the correct replacement sass file if I swap a specific components sass file using the above method. So Im not sure whether webpack and the angular compiler are doing things in a different order for component specific stylesheets

Comment: Where did youi add that fileReplacement section? In the serve or build configuration?

Comment: Hi @David. Heres the json structure leading to the variants. projects -> projectName -> architect -> configurations -> production or newConfig

Comment: Are you using angular 6.1?

Comment: @David Yup 6.1.5

Comment: I just upgraded to 6.1 to check too and I have the same problem. It's probably a bug then https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11504, https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11451

Comment: @David Huge thanks for your bit of help. Ill carry on trying and update this thread if I come up with a solution. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You need to udpate `@angular-devkit/build-angular` as well for it work:

```
ng update @angular-devkit/build-angular
```